# jquery draggable and droppable start and stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why is this second if statement condition is met.

here is the code

```
$("#car").draggable({
 start: function(event, ui) {
 if (!done) return false;
 },
 stop: function(event, ui) {
 if (counter >= 40 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#win').text(winner+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');

});
```

this is the droppable

```
   $("#carDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#car",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#car")){
            $(this).addClass("correct");

            ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
            $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
            });
        }
    }
   });
```

HTML
    
        Picture

```
    <div id="soccer"><p><img src="web/soccer.png"></p></div>
    <div id="boat"><p><img src="web/boat.png"></p></div>
    <div id="car"><p><img src="web/car.png"></p></div>

</div> 
 <div class="wrap2" >

    <div id="carDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/car.png" ></p></div>
    <div id="soccerDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/soccer.png" ></p></div>
     <div id="boatDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/boat.png" ></p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I checked the length of .correct and .drop using alert box and the length of correct is 8 and the length of .drop is 5. But when i drag an image and drop it it the second if statement is working, it doesnt make sense.

Here is the full code.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  //---------------------------toggle-----------------------
$( ".picture" ).click(function() {
  $( "#picture" ).toggle();

});

//==========================================================
    var timer;
    var done = true;

    $("#startClock").click(function() {

    var counter = 60;
     var winner = 0;
    var winners = 0;
    var winnercountry= 0;
    var finish= 0;



//===============================================CAR DRAGGABLE===================

    $("#car, #boat, #soccer").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
    if (!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (counter >= 40 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#win').text(winner+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');

     $( "#picture" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
     $(".picture").toggleClass('disabled');
     $( ".numberbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#numbercontent" ).toggle();

});

       counter = 61;
    }, 500);
    winner=3;
    finish= 1;




    }
    else if (counter >= 30 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#win').text(winner+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#picture" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".picture").toggleClass('disabled');
      $( ".numberbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#numbercontent" ).toggle();

});

        counter = 61;

    }, 500);
    winner=2;
    finish =1;



    }
    else if (counter >= 1 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
   $('#win').text(winner+' '+'star'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#picture" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".picture").toggleClass('disabled');
      $( ".numberbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#numbercontent" ).toggle();

});

        counter = 61;

    }, 500);
    winner=1;
    finish =1;



    }

    }
    });

   //=========================================CAR DRAGGABLE END==========================

   //==========================================BOAT DRAGGABLE=================================

      $("#two, #five, #six").draggable({

    start: function(event, ui) {
    if (!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (counter >= 40 && $(".correct1").length == $(".drop").length) {

    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#win1').text(winners+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#numbercontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".numberbutton").toggleClass('disabled');
     $( ".countrybutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#countrycontent").toggle();

});

        counter = 61;

    }, 500);
    winners=3;
    finish =2;

    }
    else if (counter >= 30 && $(".correct1").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#win1').text(winners+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#numbercontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".numberbutton").toggleClass('disabled');
     $( ".countrybutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#countrycontent" ).toggle();

});

        counter = 61;
    }, 500);
    winners=2;
    finish =2;

    }
    else if (counter >= 1 && $(".correct1").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#win1').text(winners+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#numbercontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".numberbutton").toggleClass('disabled');
     $( ".countrybutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#countrycontent" ).toggle();

});

        counter = 61;
    }, 500);
    winners=1;
    finish =2;

    }

    }
    });

    $("#canada, #japan, #china").draggable({

    start: function(event, ui) {
    if (!done) return false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (counter >= 40 && $(".correct2").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#winnercountry').text(winnercountry+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#countrycontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".countrybutton").toggleClass('disabled');
       clearInterval(timer);
        $("<div title='You did it!'>"+'Total Score:'+ ' '+ total+' Star(s)'+'<br>'+'<a href="Midterm.html">Play Again</a>'+"</div>").dialog();


    }, 500);
    winnercountry=3;
    total = winnercountry + winners + winner;

    }
    else if (counter >= 30 && $(".correct2").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#winnercountry').text(winnercountry+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#countrycontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".countrybutton").toggleClass('disabled');
       clearInterval(timer);
          $("<div title='You did it!'>"+'Total Score:'+ ' '+ total+' Star(s)'+'<br>'+'<a href="Midterm.html">Play Again</a>'+"</div>").dialog();


    }, 500);
    winnercountry=2;
     total = winnercountry + winners + winner;

    }
    else if (counter >= 1 && $(".correct2").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#winnercountry').text(winnercountry+' '+'stars'+' '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
   $( "#countrycontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".countrybutton").toggleClass('disabled');
       clearInterval(timer);
          $("<div title='You did it!'>"+'Total Score:'+ ' '+ total+' Star(s)'+'<br>'+'<a href="Midterm.html">Play Again</a>'+"</div>").dialog();

    }, 500);
    winnercountry=1;
     total = winnercountry + winners + winner;

    }

    }
    });



    if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
    $("#count").text(counter);
    }
    if (counter === 0 && winner === 0 && finish === 0) {
    $('#win').text(winner+' '+'Star earned');
     $( "#picture" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".picture").addClass('disabled');
     $( ".numberbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#numbercontent" ).toggle();

});
     counter=60;
        winner=0;
        finish = 1;

    }
      if (counter >= 0) {
    $("#count").text(counter);
    }
    if (counter === 0 && winners === 0  && finish === 1) {
    $('#win1').text(winners+' '+'Star earned');
     $( "#numbercontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".numberbutton").addClass('disabled');

     $( ".countrybutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#countrycontent" ).toggle();

});
     counter=60;
       winners=0;
       finish = 2;
    }
      if (counter === 0 && winnercountry === 0 && finish === 2) {
    $('#winnercountry').text(winnercountry+' '+'Star earned');
     $( "#countrycontent" ).hide( "fold", 500 );
    $(".countrybutton").addClass('disabled');
     $("<div title='Oh no!'>"+'Total Score:'+ ' '+ total+' Star(s)'+'<br>'+'<a href="Midterm.html">Play Again</a>'+"</div>").dialog();

     counter=60;
      clearInterval(timer);


    }
    total = winnercountry + winners + winner;

    }, 1000);


    }


    });
//==================================================END SOCCER DRAGGABLE================================

//===================================================CAR DROPPABLE================================
    $("#carDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#car",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#car")){
                $(this).addClass("correct");

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                });
            }
        }
    });
//===================================================CAR DROPPABLE END================================

//===================================================BOAT DROPPABLE================================
  $("#boatDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#boat",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#boat")){

                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });
//===================================================BOAT DROPPABLE END================================

//===================================================SOCCER DROPPABLE================================
  $("#soccerDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#soccer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#soccer")){

                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });
     $("#twoDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#two",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#two")){

                $(this).addClass("correct1").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });
     $("#fiveDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#five",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#five")){

                $(this).addClass("correct1").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });
      $("#sixDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#six",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#six")){

                $(this).addClass("correct1").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });
       $("#canadaDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#canada",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#canada")){

                $(this).addClass("correct2").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });

  $("#chinaDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#china",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#china")){

                $(this).addClass("correct2").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });

  $("#japanDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#japan",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#japan")){

                $(this).addClass("correct2").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;

                ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
                $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
    }
  });

//===================================================SOCCER DROPPABLE END================================
  //=============================================================END OF PICTURE GAME==============================================================================
  //=============================================================END OF PICTURE GAME==============================================================================


});
```

```css
.wrap{

            width: 40%;



                float: left;
                height: 500px;
                margin-right: 70px;
                margin-top: 10px;


         }
         .wrap2{

         width: 40%;


                float: left;
                   height: 500px;
                margin-top: 10px;

         }




         #startClock{
             background-color: #f1666a;
            padding: 10px;
         }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;

            }

         img{
            width: 100px;

         }
           #win, #win1, #winnercountry{

          font-weight: bold;
          font: 100px;
               color: white;
          margin-bottom: 50px;
         }

        #picture, #numbercontent, #countrycontent{

            width: 100%;

            height: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
             display: none;


          }
         .picture, .numberbutton, .countrybutton{
             background-color: #f1666a;
         padding: 10px;


          }



         #container{
          width: 30%;
             background-color: #f1666a;
          float: left;

         }
          #twoDrop img, #sixDrop img{
            width: 160px;
            height: 120px;
            }
            #fiveDrop img{
              width: 160px;
              height: 160px;
            }

           #scorecontainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
          }
          #win, #win1, #winnercountry{
            float: left;
            width: 30%;

          }
            .disabled {
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         background-color: gray;
          }
          body{
              background-color: #a2d5e8;
          }


         </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <header id="header">
        <div id="content" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6 pull-right align-right white" style="max-width: 540px;">
                    <div style="display: block;">

                        <a id="startClock" class="blink" href="javascript:toggle();" style="display: inline-block;" >Start Game</a>
                        <span id="count">60</span> seconds
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>

    </header> <!--// END CONTENT //-->

    <br><br>
    <div id="scorecontainer">
        <div id="win">Level 1 Score</div>
    <div id="win1">Level 2 Score</div>
    <div id="winnercountry">Level 3 Score</div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <a href="#" class="picture">Picture</a>
    <div id="picture">
     <div class="wrap" >
       Drag Me
        <div id="soccer"><p><img src="web/soccer.png"></p></div>
        <div id="boat"><p><img src="web/boat.png"></p></div>
        <div id="car"><p><img src="web/car.png"></p></div>

    </div> <!--// END WRAPPER //-->
     <div class="wrap2" >
         Drop me
        <div id="carDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/car.png" ></p></div>
        <div id="soccerDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/soccer.png" ></p></div>
         <div id="boatDrop" class="drop ui-droppable"><p><img src="web/boat.png" ></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <!--========================================Container for Number game============================================-->
    <div id="container">
        <a href="#" class="numberbutton">Numbers</a>
        <div id="numbercontent">
            <div class="wrap" >
               Drag Me
            <div id="two"><p><img src="web/0.png"></p></div>
            <div id="five"><p><img src="web/two.png"></p></div>
            <div id="six"><p><img src="web/six.png"></p></div>

            </div> <!--// END WRAPPER //-->
            <div class="wrap2" >
               Drop me
                <div id="twoDrop"><p><img src="web/44.png" ></p></div>
                <div id="fiveDrop"><p><img src="web/5.png" ></p></div>
                <div id="sixDrop"><p><img src="web/3.png" ></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="container">
            <a href="#" class="countrybutton">Country</a>
            <div id="countrycontent">
               <div class="wrap" >
                   Drag Me
                   <div id="china"><p>China</p></div>
                   <div id="japan"><p>Japan</p></div>
                   <div id="canada"><p>Canada</p></div>

              </div> <!--// END WRAPPER //-->
              <div class="wrap2" >
                 Drop me
                   <div id="japanDrop"><p><img src="web/japan.png" ></p></div>
                   <div id="canadaDrop"><p><img src="web/canada.png" ></p></div>
                   <div id="chinaDrop"><p><img src="web/china.png" ></p></div>

               </div>
            </div>
       </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Make a working fiddle of this, it'll be much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Fix your script. It looks like it is missing too many '{'. This might be the reason. Also what is the value of done and counter? Cannot see any declaration for this. Provide your HTML too. This might help. I created a script on my own. It is working.

Comment: i updated my post https://fiddle.jshell.net/lawnyan/remaak5k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition is met because counter is initialized to 60 which is greater than 40 and when you drop all the div into the slots the count of elements having the class "correct" will be equal to the count of elements having the class "drop ". i.e 3

Answer (score 0):

I see from your fiddle that counter is initialised to 60. This makes the first part of your `if` statement true (`counter >= 40`) which is why it is working as it should.

Comment: but its and (&&) not or( ||).
 counter >= 40 && $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length
if means the counter and the length condition must be met

Comment: I dont see any class="correct" or class="drop" in your fiddle. Maybe they are resolving to 'undefined' and thats why the second part of your query is true?

Comment: there is correct class and drop class i updated my post for you to see it easily

Comment: You are adding the "correct" class in the droppable's `drop` callback. I suspect the draggable's `stop` is triggered before the droppable's `drop` and so the `.addClass('correct')` has not been executed yet.

Comment: if thats the reason then the if statement shouldnt be executed

Comment: It will be executed. Why don't you open the console and run this?

if( $(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) { console.log('hello'); }

Comment: yeah tried it and printed  hello. But its not suppose to happen because correct.lengthqeual to 8 and drop.length is equal to 5 . So if 8 == 5 is false